# Conditonal replacement of a file in C

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make, conditional-compilation

In order to compare two data structures, I would like to conditionally use one or the other c file which both implement the same interface. However, I can't figure out how to do it... I'm using `GNU Make` with `gcc` ; the c files are `array_storage.c` and `tree_storage.c`, implementing the interface of `storage.h` (whose details are irrelevant here).

Here is my current `Makefile`, beware, it is a bit messy :

```makefile
TARGET  := kppv

CC      := gcc

CFLAGS       := -c -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c89 -O3
DEBUG_CFLAGS := -c -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c89 -g -Og 

LDFLAGS       := -lm `pkg-config --libs-only-other --libs-only-L MLV`
DEBUG_LDFLAGS := -g $(LDFLAGS)

LDLIBS     := `pkg-config --libs-only-l MLV`
MLVFLAGS   := `pkg-config --cflags MLV`

BINDIR    := ./bin
DEBUGDIR  := ./debug
OBJDIR    := ./obj
SRCDIR    := ./src
TESTDIR   := ./test

SOURCES      := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
OBJECTS      := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
DEBUGOBJECTS := $(OBJECTS:$(OBJDIR)/%.o=$(DEBUGDIR)/%.do)
MAINS        := $(OBJDIR)/main.o

TESTSOURCES := $(wildcard $(TESTDIR)/*.c)
TESTS       := $(TESTSOURCES:$(TESTDIR)/%.c=$(BINDIR)/%)

all  : $(TARGET)
debug: $(TARGET).db
test : $(TESTS)

ifneq (,$(findstring l,$(firstword -$(MAKEFLAGS))))
  $(SOURCES) := $(filter-out ./src/tree_storage.c, $(SOURCES))
else
  $(SOURCES) := $(filter-out ./src/array_storage.c, $(SOURCES))
endif

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(TARGET).db: $(DEBUGOBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(DEBUG_LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

$(DEBUGOBJECTS): $(DEBUGDIR)/%.do : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    mkdir -p $(DEBUGDIR)
    $(CC) $(DEBUG_CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(TESTS): $(BINDIR)/%_test : $(TESTDIR)/%_test.c $(filter-out $(MAINS), $(OBJECTS))
    mkdir -p $(TESTDIR)
    mkdir -p $(BINDIR)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
    $@

clean:
    cd ./obj && rm -rf ./*
    cd ./debug && rm -rf ./*
    rm -f $(TARGET) $(TARGET).db
```

The current idea (important bit from `ifneq` to `endif`) is that I would filter out `tree.o` or `array.o` conditionally from the objects, passing argument `-l` when I want to use arrays. Unfortunately this doesn't work, `gcc` complains about functions being defined twice (which they are, since the filtering doesn't take place)

---

META : if someone can tell me what I should put after the triple backtick for proper Makefile syntax highlighting, that would also be great

---

UPDATE : For now, I'm trying to just filter the files from the `SOURCES` directly instead of the objects. However, I have ran into another weird problem. This works :

```makefile
SOURCES := $(filter-out ./src/tree_storage.c, $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c))
```

but this doesn't :

```makefile
SOURCES := $(filter-out %storage%, $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c))
```

However, I have checked that `%` is indeed the wildcard character in this context, and it **is**, filtering out `%` directly filters everything out. I have no idea what's happening.

Comment: How about you just build two different (and differently-named) programs, one that uses tree.o and the other that uses array.o?  Among the advantages are: (i) you know which version you're looking at by its name, and (ii) you can have both at the same time, and you don't need to rebuild to switch.

Comment: META: lang-makefile

Comment: @JohnBollinger That still requires excluding the files, which I'm currently trying to do with `filter-out` but for some reason that's not working either

Comment: It does not.  You have created that problem for yourself by using `$(wildcard)` to identify your sources.  I always recommend specifying source files (or object files, your choice) *explicitly*, which would solve this particular problem.  Alternatively, you could put tree.c and array.c in a different directory, so that they are not picked up by your `$(wildcard)` in the first place.  Or you could adjust your file names to allow you to write a source-file glob that doesn't pick them up.

Comment: What happens if you use `:=` instead of `=` when filtering out? Would it be better to filter `SOURCES` instead (before constructing `OBJECTS` by substitution)?

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes about filtering sources, and the `:=` should just change that the filtering is run only once instead of every time the variable is invoked

Comment: Then if you want to keep using `=`, at least use a new variable for the left hand side and make your target depend on the new variable.

Comment: @IanAbbott I have replaced `=` with `:=`, however it seems neither part of the condition is ever run : I added echo commands to both, and neither message printed to the console.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Explicitly listing the source files ? Even when there are multiple dozens of them ?

Comment: Yes, @ice-wind, even if there are hundreds of them.  Not that it's particularly hard to do even then.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Shouldn't you just split your project at that point ? Clearly if you have multiple executables with very different lists of source files, you're building multiple different products with only some common code that likely should be a library instead.

Comment: Who said anything about multiple executables, @ice-wind?  However, projects that provide suites of multiple binaries (executables and / or libraries) are in fact relatively common, so no, I don't take that alone as a good indicator of whether to split a project.  Nor either the number of source files, regardless of the number of binaries.  But this is tangential.  Across all of that, my recommendation remains to explicitly list all the sources that the build system needs to take into account.

Comment: Why do you filter `SOURCES` **after** computing `OBJECTS`? And, more important, why don't you filter `OBJECTS` instead of `SOURCES`? After all, it is `OBJECTS` that is used to build `TARGET`, not `SOURCES`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Please check my solution for the first mistake. As for the other question, filtering the sources or the objects should both work, however I would rather filter earlier rather than later to make sure there aren't any duplicates. But both should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution, which is twofold :

- Remove the `$()` around the variables in the second assignment
- Filter `SOURCES` **before** `OBJECTS` is defined

```makefile
SOURCES      := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)

ifneq (,$(findstring l,$(firstword -$(MAKEFLAGS))))
    SOURCES := $(filter-out ./src/stockage_arbre.c, $(SOURCES))
else
    SOURCES := $(filter-out ./src/stockage_tableau.c, $(SOURCES))
endif

OBJECTS      := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
```

Also good to know : `filter-out` appears to only work when a single wildcard is included. If someone can explain why this is the case, that would be quite nice.

Comment: The filter functions don't use "wildcards" they use patterns (the `%`).  A pattern means that the same value is replaced in all instances.  So, if it were supported to use `%foo%` then this would only match strings which started and ended with the same string.  So it would match `XXXfooXXX`, but it would not match `XXXfooYYY` or `XXXfooX` etc.  But this is not supported anyway, even with this restriction.  GNU Make doesn't provide a `filter`-like function that accepts wildcards (shell globbing like `*` etc.) or regular expressions.

Comment: @MadScientist Thank you for the explanation ! Feeding the output of the `wildcard` function to `filter-out` does provide basically the same functionality.